# Authorization code not exchanged for token facebook by mobile app

Tags: facebook, cordova, azure-ad-b2c

I am using `cordova-plugin-ms-adal-b2c-patch- cordova plugin` with `Azure b2c`
I created a facebook developer account with the relevant definitions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-fb-app)

The domain is : `https://login.microsoftonline.com`
The redirect URI is : `https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{{My tenent}}/oauth2/authresp`

On the first login it worked from the second it stopped working with the following error:

> Authorization code not exchanged for token

Comment: The redirect URI should be`https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`.

Comment: I am getting the following error: - in the mobile appURL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs.